# Linear vs. Non-Linear ODE on Manifold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds

This is truly a stupid and naive question, but is there a notion of linear vs. non-linear ODE on a closed, connected, Riemannian manifold? I'm still learning out of [Transversal Mappings and Flows by Abraham and Robbin](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B0006BR4GQ/) and [Foundations of Mechanics by Abraham and Marsden](https://smile.amazon.com/Foundations-Mechanics-AMS-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821844385/).

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that material to consider differential equations on manifolds. :)

Consider a continuous map $X\colon \mathbb R\times M\to TM$ (we can call it a time-dependent vector field). An ordinary differential equation is of the form $x'=X(t,x)$ and the solutions are $C^1$ functions such that $x'(t)=X(t,x(t))$ on their domain.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Those are first-order ODEs on closed, connected, Riemannian manifolds. They obey the Poincare-Hopf Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem, for instance. While it's true you can lift any order ODE on a manifold to its nth tangent bundle, making it a first-order ODE on the nth tangent bundle, the nth tangent bundle is no longer closed and so the Poincare-Hopf Theorem no longer applies, for instance, even thought the manifold and its tangent bundle share the same Euler characteristic.

Comment: Also, only vector fields on the double tangent bundle that obey the canonical flip https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_tangent_bundle#Secondary_vector_bundle_structure_and_canonical_flip on the double tangent bundle are second-order ordinary differential equations on $M$. So, there is a little more to the theory than what you outline above. Thanks again for the reply!

Comment: You never mentioned that are thinking of "second-order" so I don't see our your comment can relate to my answer. Do study geodesic flows, if that's the case, without the huge complication of geometers!